# Using Python Requests with just a password

Tags: python-requests

I'm trying to use Requests to login to a website that only has a password field, no username.  Anytime I try and do a request using simply:

```
response = requests.get(URL, auth = ('password'), verify=False)
```

All I get is the HTML formatting of the page asking for the password, which is the following:

```
'<html><head>\t<title>Relay Diagnostics Login page</title></head><body>\t<form action="/rd" method="POST">\t\tPlease, enter the password to access the Relay Diagnostics page:\t\t<br />\t\t<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />\t\t<br />\t\t<input type="submit" value="Login" />\t\t<input type="hidden" name="rnd" value="WtKEYTI64T3InibBmG+OKVM9dIo" />\t</form></body></html>'
```

Is there anyway to pass auth with just a password?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its rare for site to only have password. Try `auth=('','password')` or `auth=(None,'password')`